# An invalid character was found when trying to add multiple MailMessage.To addresses

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error when I add two or more TO email addresses in the method below.

If I only have one email it works fine, but it errors when there is more than one email in the string.

> Error: An invalid character was found in the mail header: ','

I tried different methods online but nothing is working.

```
EmailSender.SendMailMessage("test1@yahoo.org,test2@yahoo.org", "test3@test.org", 
    changeContro_test.subject, body, AttachementList, ChangeId);

public static void SendMailMessage(string toEmail, string fromEmail, string subject, 
    string body, List<string> attachmentFullPath,int ChangeId)
{
    MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();

    mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);

    // set the recipient address of the mail message
    mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmail)); //error happens here
```

Comment: Are you sending the emails via `Outlook`?

Comment: I would re-read what `To` [really](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to?view=netframework-4.8) is.

Comment: This is because you need to pass it in as a list if it is more then one email that your sending it too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split your string

Something like this:

```cs
foreach(var email in toEmail.Split(','))
   mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
```

or

```
foreach(var email in toEmail.Split(new[] {',', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
```

as RufusL said

Obs:
`To` is a MailAddressCollection, so you can add how many addresses you need.

Comment: I'm not sure the `.ToList()` is necessary here.